# Custom input style with a icon inside and button in the right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

I am trying to get a custom input style have a glyph icon inside and have a button on the right that says go.

Here is my js fiddle with it. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/843q9vv8/)

```
<div class="form-group">
<div class="icon-addon addon-sm">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search All Orders" class="form-control" id="Order Search">
<label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
</div>
</div>
```

The problem i am having is when i try to add the button on the right it makes the icon disappear when the input is clicked.

Comment: Do you have an example of you adding a button on the right? Is the button inside the input or outside? If it is inside, you may have an issue with the clear button that many browsers have now.

An example of the button would be useful to see what you're trying to do so we can also help with edge cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your fiddle I simply added an absolutely positioned button into your search box. Perhaps this is what you were looking for?

Added button in HTML:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Search All Orders" class="form-control" id="Order Search">
<label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
<button class="button-go">go</button>
```

Button's CSS:

```
.button-go {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height: 30px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t6295xrd/

Answer (score 1):

Here is a  [Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/b4y1wL5o/) for what i understood from you i just add the button to your fiddle and add this css to position it on right.

```
#Order_Search {
    padding-right:20px;
}
.go-btn {
    position: absolute;
    right: 3px;
    margin-left: -2.5px;
    top: 2px
}
```

and this is the html

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="icon-addon addon-sm">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Search All Orders" class="form-control" id="Order_Search">
    <label for="email" class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" rel="tooltip" title="email"></label>
    <button class="go-btn"> Go </button>
</div>
```